# Cannot pull MS SQL Server data using Excel (Permissions issue?)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I recently (today, actually) got some new permissions to some MS SQL Server tables (of SAP software), but I'm getting permissions issues with importing them.  Here's how my process looks right now:

1. I have an Access database that links to SAP tables via an ODBC connection.
2. In that same Access database, a set of spaghetti-like queries pulls & refines a modest data set (a dozen columns, few hundred rows, nothing special). I can run these queries without a problem.
3. An Excel file imports that data using **Data->Import External Data->Import Data**.  I do this all the time.  Except this time, I'm getting the dialog pictured below. Clicking **OK** doesn't seem to do anything.  Clicking **Cancel** produces an "ODBC Connection Failure" message (or something like that).

[image]

Again, these queries can be run from Access just fine.  But when I import those query results into Excel, I get this problem.  I can get around it with a make-table query, but since someone else is maintaining the Access database, I'd rather not make any changes to it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, from your description it sounds like the connection the the ACCESS DB is failing, not the connection to SAP - when running the query from Access do you use the same login credentials as when you are importing into Excel? Are there any other queries that you are able to open in Excel without problems?  All I can suggest is to get an ABAP or BASIS person to help you run an SQL or Authorisation trace in SAP (Try Transactions ST01; ST05 - also ask them to check the RFC & ODBC Connections in SAP) But given that Access connects fine, my guess is that the problem is not within SAP

Comment: So I don't have an answer for you - but why on earth would you do this rather than writing an abap program to perform the same functions?  An ALV Grid is easily sent to excel if you really need excel as the final format.

Comment: @Esti, I have all the trusted login options checked so that I don't have to enter any login credentials.  Also, didn't mention this earlier, but I do this stuff all the time using SQL Server as my data source. The only difference this time is that I'm now connecting to SAP.

Comment: @Bryan, SAP is not my area of expertise.  I googled ALV grids and abap programs and they seem to be native to SAP.  But I can tell you that this process is also quite simple. If I do it manually, no code is even required.  Automated, a VBA script handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going thru my old unanswered questions and found this one.  I think I solved this by using a staging table in Access to store the data and then later importing into Excel from that staging table.